# Tkinter: Cannot edit entry widget after 2nd selection

Tags: python, tkinter

I've made a simple GUI for placing objects in RoboDK via a Python script using Tkinter.

Essentailly, the user selects an object using the `btnSelect` button, which then updates the entry widgets with its coordinates (x, y, z, then Euler rotation). The user can then edit the entry widgets then select the "Move object" button (or `btnMove` in the code) to move the object to the new position. However, when selecting an object for the second time, the entry fields cannot be edited without selecting a new object.

```py
from tkinter.constants import DISABLED, NORMAL, CENTER, END
from typing import *
import tkinter as tk
import threading

from robolink import *    # RoboDK API
from robodk import *      # Robot toolbox

X_MAX = 500
X_MIN = 0
Y_MAX = 300
Y_MIN = -360
ROTZ_MAX = 180
ROTZ_MIN = -180

# Keep track of selected item
obj = None

def main():
    rdk = Robolink()
    window = buildGUI(rdk)
    window.mainloop()

def buildGUI(rdk: Robolink) -> tk.Tk:
    window = tk.Tk()
    canvas = tk.Canvas(window, width=200)
    canvas.grid(columnspan=3, rowspan=14)

    # Set the window title (must be unique for the docking to work, try to be creative)
    window_title = 'Move object window'
    window.title(window_title)

    title = tk.Label(window, text="Move Object", font="none 14 bold")
    title.grid(columnspan=3, column=0, row=0)

    # Delete the window when we close it
    window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: onClose(window))

    deadspace1 = tk.Label(text="")
    deadspace1.grid(columnspan=3, column=0, row=1)

    selectText = tk.StringVar()
    btnSelect = tk.Button(window, textvariable=selectText, height=2, width=0,
                        bg="#bbbbbb", fg='white', justify=CENTER)
    selectText.set("Select object")
    btnSelect.grid(column=1, row=2)

    deadspace2 = tk.Label("")
    deadspace2.grid(columnspan=3, column=0, row=3)

    objName = tk.StringVar()
    objLabel = tk.Label(window, textvariable=objName, font="none 12 bold")
    objName.set("None Selected")
    objLabel.grid(columnspan=3, column=0, row=4)

    deadspace2 = tk.Label("")
    deadspace2.grid(columnspan=3, column=0, row=5)

    # Position options

    xLabel = tk.Label(window, text="x: ", font='none 12')
    xLabel.grid(column=0, row=6)
    xEntry = tk.Entry(window, width=10)
    xEntry.grid(columnspan=2, column=1, row=6)

    yLabel = tk.Label(window, text="y: ", font='none 12')
    yLabel.grid(column=0, row=7)
    yEntry = tk.Entry(window, width=10)
    yEntry.grid(columnspan=2, column=1, row=7)

    zLabel = tk.Label(window, text="z: ", font='none 12')
    zLabel.grid(column=0, row=8)
    zEntry = tk.Entry(window, width=10)
    zEntry.grid(columnspan=2, column=1, row=8)

    # Rotation options

    rxLabel = tk.Label(window, text="rx: ", font='none 12')
    rxLabel.grid(column=0, row=9)
    rxEntry = tk.Entry(window, width=10)
    rxEntry.grid(columnspan=2, column=1, row=9)

    ryLabel = tk.Label(window, text="ry: ", font='none 12')
    ryLabel.grid(column=0, row=10)
    ryEntry = tk.Entry(window, width=10)
    ryEntry.grid(columnspan=2, column=1, row=10)

    rzLabel = tk.Label(window, text="rz: ", font='none 12')
    rzLabel.grid(column=0, row=11)
    rzEntry = tk.Entry(window, width=10)
    rzEntry.grid(columnspan=2, column=1, row=11)

    entries = [xEntry, yEntry, zEntry, rzEntry, ryEntry, rxEntry]

    deadspace3 = tk.Label(text="")
    deadspace3.grid(columnspan=3, column=0, row=12)

    btnMove = tk.Button(window, text="Move object", height=2, width=0,
                        bg="#bbbbbb", fg='white', justify=CENTER,
                        command=lambda: moveObject(entries))
    btnMove.grid(column=1, row=13)

    selectCallback = lambda: select_item(rdk, selectText, objName, entries)
    btnSelect['command'] = selectCallback

    EmbedWindow(window_title)
    return window

# Close the window
def onClose(window: tk.Tk):
    window.destroy()
    quit(0)

def select_item(rdk: Robolink, selectText: tk.StringVar, objName: tk.Label,
                entries: List[tk.Entry]):
    def thread_btnSelect():
        selectText.set("Waiting...")
        item = rdk.ItemUserPick('Select an item', ITEM_TYPE_OBJECT)

        if item.Valid():
            global obj
            obj = item
            objName.set(item.Name())
            updateObjectPosition(item, entries)
        
        selectText.set("Select object")
        
    # Prevent RoboDK from freezing
    threading.Thread(target=thread_btnSelect).start()

def updateObjectPosition(item: Item, entries: List[tk.Entry]):
    pose = item.Pose()
    coords = Pose_2_KUKA(pose)

    for entry, coord in zip(entries, coords):
        entry.delete(0, END)
        entry.insert(0, str(coord))

def moveObject(entries: tk.Entry):
    global obj

    if obj is None:
        ShowMessage("No object selected")
        return

    try:
        coords = getCoords(entries)
        obj.setPose(KUKA_2_Pose(coords))
    except Exception as err:
        ShowMessage(str(err))

def getCoords(entries: List[tk.Entry]) -> list:
    coords = [0] * 6

    for i, entry in enumerate(entries):
        coords[i] = float(entry.get())
    
    return coords

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using a tkinter.Variable such as tkinter.DoubleVar with your entries should fix this issue. You can also use tkinter.DoubleSpin for convenience.

```
x, y, z, rx, ry, rz = Pose_2_TxyzRxyz(item.Pose())
xVar = tk.DoubleVar(value=x)
xEntry = tk.Spinbox(window, textvariable=xVar, format="%.2f", from_=-9999999, to=9999999)
xVal = xVal.get()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).